# Drupal does not detect an installed module

Tags: drupal-6

I have a number of sites running off a single Drupal core installation.

This includes a number of 'standard' modules such as Views and CCK in the `/sites/all/modules` directory.

This works fine apart from one issue.

One of the sites refuses to accept that the Google Analytics module is installed. It can see all the other modules in the directory, and all the other sites see and use the Analytics module without any issue.

I've tried clearing the cache and checked the permissions but the fact the module works for other sites, and the problem site can see the other modules has got me stumped.

Any ideas?

**Edit** : Ok, case closed. It was me being a muppet. I forgot the first rule, which is check all your assumptions. In this case I assumed I was looking at the right site. Wrong. For reasons best kept to myself, I have 2 instances of this site hosted, one of which the domain name resolves to, and one which it doesn't. I was looking at the 'orphan' site's drupal installation, not the correct installation which works perfectly.... now I've actually installed the module.

Sorry to have wasted your time, but rest assured, I wasted far more or my own time, and hopefully this question will serve as a reminder to others to check their assumptions too :-)

Comment: does it appear in the systems table in the database?

Comment: Good catch, no it doesn't! I thought that was refreshed when visiting the module admin page. Either it's not, or as kiamlaluno suggested, there's something wrong with the module itself. (But then how come it works for other sites....?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean that this module is not showing up in the modules list, or that it is not showing any data from this particular instance after it is enabled.

If  this is a case where the module is installed but not working properly you should make sure that you have not removed the

```
<?php print $closure ?>
```

tag from the end of the theme for that particular instance of drupal. If it is removed then the GA javascript code will not be added to the page.

Comment: It's effectively invisible to one of the installed sites. Not listed on the modules page, and no configuration options exist for it.

Comment: Have you tried using one of the standard drupal themes as the administrator theme. Since you have several sites running off the one drupal base it makes me think there is something going on within the files specific to the trouble instance.

Comment: Good thought, but I always use Bluemarine as the admin theme as I've suffered from theme 'misbehaviour' in the past. (And when I'm developing themes I tend to screw something up :-) )

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that there are some missing files; in particular, if the `.info` file is missing, the module is not listed in the modules page. The same is true if the `.module` file is missing.

It's not a problem with the permission, as users who can access the page listing all the modules will see all the modules (with the exception of the modules with missing files).

Comment: That was the kind of thing I was thinking, but the same module works perfectly for the other sites installed on that Drupal instance.